# Taking math operators from Unicode font, but chars from text

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, mathastext

since I've found a nice font (oldstandard), I'm doing my very first steps using XeLaTeX. This font has enough math operators for me, but unfortunately covers no mathmematical alphanumeric signs.

So using unicode math, I get the correct operators from the font, but no greek letters. When using mathspec, I get greek letters (which then origin from the greek text block), but the Computer Modern math operators instead of the Old Standard ones. How to get both symbols and letters from a font while mapping math greek to text greek letters?

MWE: This prints correct letters, but wrong symbols:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Old Standard TT Regular}
\setmathsfont(Latin,Greek,Symbols){Old Standard TT Regular}
%\setmathfont{Old Standard TT Regular}
\begin{document}
AV
\[
    A= \sum V\oplus\alpha^\varkappa
\]
\end{document}
```

Exchanging the commented lines with the line above respectively yields correct symbols but wrong letters.

Comment: `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathfont{Old Standard}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Old Standard Italic}

\begin{document}
AV
\[
A= \sum_{i=1}^n V_i\oplus\alpha^\varkappa
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, `range={it->up}` is better since your solution uses CM for latin italic (e. g. math A and V are CM)

Comment: @Bubaya Fixed; also Latin letters are printed with Old Standard.

Comment: \sum and \int of Old Standard are quite small and have the same size in display and inline math. Is there an easy way to fix this (make them bigger and have different sizes in display/inline)? This might need a separate question, but maybe it has been answered already, though I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is a good idea to use a text font as math font. A math not only need symbols but also quite a number of other information. Imho it is better to use as base a real math font and to exchange only single symbols with symbols from a text font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}]{Arial Unicode MS}
\setmathfont[range=it/{greek,Greek}]{Arial Unicode MS}
%Just to make sure that all math fontdimens are from a math font:
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}

\[
    V\oplus V \quad \alpha^\varkappa \Gamma
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand your doubts. I just wanted to have a look how this font looks like and wondered how to use it in math for testing. I suppose I'll stick to CM anyway.